# How do you save global arrays in the applicationWillTerminate and reload them in the application function?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

So I have been trying to make an app for my Mobile Apps Development class and I need to find a solution to a problem that I'm having when I save a global array called "events".

Here I tried to reload the saved event class in AppDelegate but it didn't change in the main screen view controller:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    //Override point for customization after application launch.
    //Load the events that were saved when application was terminated
    let eventKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    Global.events = (eventKey.arrayForKey("savedEvents") as? [Event])!
    return true
}
```

Here is the function that is called when someone quits the app:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    let myEvents = Global.events
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myEvents, forKey: "savedEvents")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

This might just be an error in the viewcontroller that displays this array but if you see something wrong with the code please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- In iOS, there is no such thing as "someone quits the app", and thus what you're doing is unlikely to work, because `applicationWillTerminate` is never called. Save when the application is deactivated or backgrounded.
- An array of Event cannot magically be saved in user defaults, because Event is not a Property List type. You will need to make Event archivable and archive the array.